# Alarm API on internally developed chrome extension not working properly after migration to Manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api

Two years ago, we developed a custom Chrome Extension using **manifest v2** which triggers popups either at regular intervals *(every 45 mins or 20 mins after being snoozed)* or scheduled notifications *(daily or weekly)*.

The Extension allows configurable time intervals by using the `chrome.alarms` API to schedule code to "run periodically or at a specified time in the future".

After upgrading the extension to use **manifest v3**, following the instructions in the [Manifest v3 migration checklist](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration-checklist/), we ran multiple tests which failed. We think it's because the `chrome.alarms` API won't trigger or get triggered if the extension is idle for a day or more.

The problem started after migrating to **manifest v3**. The `chrome.alarms` API doesn't fire daily nor at the interval set, and it doesn't show any notifications.

Any ideas on how can we achieve this with **manifest v3** as we did with manifest v2?
What should we be looking at?
Has anyone else seen this issue?

```
function triggerAlarm() {
    chrome.storage.local.get(['delayInMinutes'],function(res){
        console.log(res);
//code for creating alarm
chrome.alarms.create('createAlarm', {
            delayInMinutes:delayInMinutes
        });
    });
//code to listen the alarm
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(alarmListener);
    chrome.alarms.get('createAlarm', function (alarm) { });
}
function alarmListener(alarm) {
//business logic
}
```

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome which you can report on https://crbug.com. Meanwhile use MV2.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ? I have the exact same issue : chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener does not seem to reactivate the service worker, even when registered in the top level of the script

Answer (score 1):

This does not work because you register the `alarms.create` event listener asynchronously. As described in, event listeners must be registered synchronously from the start of the page in root scope.

If you move the event listener out of `triggerAlarm()` and into the root scope, the event handler fires as expected.

See the full answer: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1295683